# When I compress a tar gz file using paths, folders get included

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, redhat, tar

When I compress a tar gz file using paths, folders get included. However, I want to just compress the file only. This is what I tried:

```
$ tar -czf ../coolfile.tar.gz newfol/coolfile
```

When I uncompress this tar.gz, I get the `coolfile` file in newfol folder. I would like compress `coolfile` only.

Uncompress tar gz command:

```
$ tar -xvf coolfile.tar.gz`
```

Comment: `(cd newfol && tar -czf ../../coolfile.tar.gz coolfile)` but why not just `gzip -c newfol/coolfile > ../coolfile.gz` ?

Comment: Or better, use `xz` compression for a more efficient algorithm. If you simply want to compress a file, don't create a Tape Archive (`tar`), instead, just compress the file, e.g. `gzip file`, or `bzip2 file` or `xz file`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks. I followed your advice and used gzip without the tar. I appreciate the time and effort. I wanted to see if there was a way to tar gz a file inside a folder without the folder and it appears that you are forced to change directory. I wanted to know if There was a way to do this without cd, because I think it’s more work the script has to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tar -C newfol -cvzf coolfile.tar.gz coolfile
```

Note: you specify the tar.gz file relative to the current directory, and you specify the file(s) to be tarred relative to the directory that is argument to the -C option, and that tar will cd into to perform the tar.